# Git rm with wildcard doesn't find existing files

Tags: git, bash, wildcard

I'm trying to execute a git remove using wilcards.

```
git rm -r -f $artname-*-$buildtype
```

The $artname variable is something like "core" and the $buildtype is something like "SNAPSHOT.jar"

So if there is a file on the remote repo called "core-1.0-SNAPSHOT", it should be removed using the wildcard.

But this doesn't work. The variables do resolve but the wildcard just doesn't seem to work.

This is the error that I'm getting

```
fatal: pathspec 'core-*-SNAPSHOT.jar' did not match any files
```

I hope, that someone can help me!

Comment: Btw what's the deal with the "remote repo"? `git` can only work with files in the local one (directly, that is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [git-rm documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm), possible causes may be:

- bash expanding the glob before it reaches `git` (due to "`core-*-SNAPSHOT.jar`" in the error message, it didn't - *in your specific case* - because it didn't match anything in the directory you're in). Quote the argument to prevent this: `git rm "$artname-*-$buildtype"`
- files you're interested in are untracked (`git`'s search behaves as if they don't exist)
- leading directory name is required for `-r` to work **(the docs say so but a simple test with `git 2.7.4` shows it actually isn't)**

Answer (score 1):

A oneliner solution avoiding untracked and .gitignored files could be:

```
git ls-files $artname-*-$buildtype | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -L1 -I '$' git rm -r -f '$'
```